# Delivery Fleet not being released from Delay Block in GIS Fleet Model in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I have a model where I am trying to optimize the Fleet using GIS Integration feature in Anylogic. I am new to this field.

[image]

The above image shows my main agent. You can see there are two agent population living on the workspace,

1. parcelstationses
2. warehouses

Each agent population has 1 location ie. New York and Chicago.

Now, my objective is to deliver parcels from warehouse to parcel station. In the fuction setCenters the function body is as follows,

" for (Parcelstations parcelstations : parcelstationses)
parcelstations.set_center(parcelstations.getNearestAgentByRoute(warehouses)); "

I am pretty sure something is wrong in the above code.

[image]

It seems when I run the model the trucks get stuck in the delay block, which is set to stopDelay call.

[image]

As you can see the trucks should move to the parcel stations, and once they got there, the truck is supposed to stopdelay in the truck agent which will set the truck free. But my truck is sitting at the warehouse.

[image]

Edited on oct 4, 2023: Please also take into note that I am plotting the location of GIS Map using database of GIS NAMES. Please the see the below image for reference,

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you do traceln(order) before the stopDelay function, what do you get?

Comment: if order is not null, do this: traceln(order.currentBlock()) to see if that order you are trying to use is actually in the delay block or not

Comment: You were right, so after doing as you said. I looked into why my vehicles were not moving from warehouse to parcelstations. And it looks like I was missing the following code On Seize Unit send( agent, unit );